# How to create new item in collection if not exists, otherwise, update price and quantity when added to cart

Tags: mongodb, express, vuejs3

Hi iam new to Vue and trying too build a MEVN application. What iam trying to do is when user adds item in cart it should store one document in mongoDB and if user adds more of same item only the price and quantity for the document should increase and not create new document.

Here is code for client when user adds item in cart,iam using Vue3:

```js
async addToCart(state, product) {
      
      console.log(state);
      let dbProducts = await axios
        .get(`http://localhost:1337/items/`)
        .then((res) => res.data)
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    
    
      let item = dbProducts.find((i) => i.id === product.id);
      console.log(item);
      console.log('addTOcart');
      if (item) {
        console.log('put request');
        
        item.quantity++;
        console.log('quantity', item.quantity);
        axios
          //.put(`http://localhost:1337/items/${uniqueId}`, item)
          .put(`http://localhost:1337/items/`, item)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
            alert(res.data);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
      } else {
        product = { ...product, quantity: 1 };
        state.cart.push(product);
        axios.post('http://localhost:1337/items', {
          id: product.id,
          title: product.title,
          price: product.price,
          quantity: product.quantity,
          shortDesc: product.shortDesc,
          category: product.category,
          longDesc: product.longDesc,
          imgFile: product.imgFile,
          serial: product.serial,
        });
      }
     
    },
```

And here is code for the server, iam using express js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Items = require('./Items');
const connection = require('./connection');
const Port = process.env.Port || 1337;
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
connection();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/items', (req, res) => {
  const data = new Items(req.body);
  data
    .save()
    .then((Items) => {
      console.log('item saved', Items);
      res.json({ succcess: true, Items });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

app.get('/items', async (req, res) => {
  Items.find({}, (err, items) => {
    res.json(items);
  });
});

app.put('/items', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  //Items.updateOne({ _id: req.body._id }, req.body);
  Items.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body._id }, req.body);
  // Items.findOne({ _id: req.body._id });
});

app.listen(Port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${Port}`);
});
```

Comment: You haven't described what your problem is. However, you implement the rules (for example, the check whether the item is already in the cart) in your client-side code, which is not best practise, because such rules can always be circumvented by a malicious user. You should POST the product to the backend and implement the rules in your server-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @HeikoTheißen suggested, you should handle the logic of the operation on the server, using a single POST request:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Items = require('./Items');
const connection = require('./connection');
const Port = process.env.Port || 1337;
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
connection();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/items', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let item = await Items.findById(req.body.id);
    if (!item) {
      item = await Items.create(req.body);
    } else {
      item.quantity++;
      await item.save();
    }
    res.json({ succcess: true, item });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ succcess: false });
  }
});

app.listen(Port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${Port}`);
});
```

You should simplify your client code as:

```
async function addToCart(state, product) {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:1337/items', product);

    // Add new product to card if necessary
    if (!state.cart.some((p) => p.id === data.item.id)) {
      state.cart.push(data.item);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Since this server implementation makes _two_ database requests (first read, then write), it may fail if two _concurrent_ requests both want to add the same product: Both requests may read `item = undefined`, so both try to create an item with the same product and `quantity = 1`, which is precisely what the author wants to avoid.

Comment: Thank you very much that solved it! I appreciate ,been struggling with this problem for few days.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I think that above the concurrency problem that you mention there is the fact that `Items` are not associated to a specific user.

Comment: Two concurrent request could also be made by _one_ user (who has two browser tabs open).